# Read csv file and taking input in java

Tags: java, csv, exception

I have a csv file that I will read in the code.
But when I run the code it is showing me this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lon"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:543)
    at practise.main(practise.java:63)
```

please help me with this.

Here is my code:

```
    s1 = new Scanner(new FileReader(filename2+".csv"));
    while(s1.hasNext()){
        z = s1.nextLine();

        String[] results = z.split(",");
        double[] lon_lat = new double [2];
        lon_lat[0] = Double.parseDouble(results[1]);//longtitude
        lon_lat[1] = Double.parseDouble(results[2]);//latitude
        airportLonLat.put(Integer.parseInt(results[0]), lon_lat);
    }
```

And here is my csv data:

```
Id     lon      lat
1     -5.9300   54.5906
2     -5.9385   54.6013
3     -5.9191   54.5928
4     -5.9171   54.5992
5     -5.9273   54.5873
.......................
30    -5.9582   54.5834
```

Comment: It's a good practice to name your variables based on what they represent, so that the code is more readable and understandable even if you come back to it after two weeks. `s1` and `z` can be whatever.

Comment: @Dropout Thank you. I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program starts reading from the first line, which contains the headers. You are getting the "NumberFormatException" because it is attempting to convert the header (which is a string) to a double.

To resolve this, you can either remove the headers from the data or add a condition to skip the first row.

Hopefully, that resolves the issue.

Comment: Oh I get it now. That's the reason. Thank you.